# ERROR: THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js

**i don't know where is the problem** but on console says this error:

THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry is not a constructor

thats the code

```
function particleSetup() {
    let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader() ;

    loader. load("smoke.png", function (texture){
        portalGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(350, 350);
        portalMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
            map: texture,
            transparent: true
        });

        smokeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1000,1000);
        smokeMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial ({
            map: texture,
            transparent: true
        });

        for (let p=880;p>250;p--) {
            let particle = new THREE.Mesh(portalGeo,portalMaterial);
            particle.position.set (
                0.5 * p * Math.cos ( (4 * p * Math.PI) / 180),
                0.5 * p * Math.sin ( (4 * p * Math.PI) / 180),
                0.1 * p
            );
            particle.rotation.z = Math.random() *360;
            portalParticles.push(particle);
            scene.add(particle);
        }

        for (let p=0;p<40;p++) {
            let particle = new THREE.Mesh (smokeGeo, smokeMaterial);
            particle.position.set (
                Math.random () * 1000-500,
                Math.random () * 400-200,
                25
            );
            particle.rotation.z = Math.random () *360;
            particle.material.opacity = 0.6;
            portalParticles.push (particle);
            scene.add (particle);
        }

        clock = new THREE.Clock ();
        animate ( );

    });
}
```

These are my first tests with three.js, I've searched everywhere but I don't understand the problem, i think is something with PlaneBufferGeometry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BufferGeometry` alias for geometry generators has been deprecated with `r145` and is now removed in latest `three.js` versions. Use `PlaneGeometry` instead of `PlaneBufferGeometry`.